# Deleted Ubuntu partition, grub rescue

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

I had a system with a dual boot of Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 13. I deleted the Ubuntu partition in Disk Management in Windows, and then this problem occurred. My problem is that I can't access or boot from CD or USB, which I think is because of Windows 8.1.

Do you have any tips on how to fix it?

Comment: Wait you Can't use live CD? How did you get ubuntu on in the first place?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: can you access windows?

Answer (score 3):

You deleted the partition with the boot flag.

- Boot with Ubuntu LiveCD or LiveUSB.
- Open Gparted, look for the windows partition.
- Right click on it and select manage flags.
- Select boot.
- Apply all changes and exit gparted
- Restart PC

Comment: This worked for me, although the OP did specify not being able to boot from CD/USB.

Comment: It just corrupted my windows too!  :(
Btw, I was able to recover windows by repeating it once again.